# Align equal signs while including text over equalities

Tags: align

I understand how to align multiple equations, but how can I do this if I want to also have text over the equalities. For example:

[image]

It bugs me that the equal signs are no longer aligned. Here is my LaTeX:

```
$$
\begin{align}
p(\textbf{x} \mid \mathcal{D}, \alpha)
&= \int p(\textbf{x} \mid \boldsymbol{\theta}) p(\boldsymbol{\theta} \mid \mathcal{D}, \alpha) \text{d} \boldsymbol{\theta}
\\
&\stackrel{\text{Eq 4}}{=} \int p(\textbf{x} \mid \boldsymbol{\theta}) p(\boldsymbol{\theta} \mid \alpha') \text{d} \boldsymbol{\theta}
\\
&= p(\textbf{x} \mid \alpha'). \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Off-topic: Encasing an `align` environment inside `$$ ... $$` cannot possibly work correctly -- at least not as a LaTeX document. Please be more precise about you actually do.

Comment: Fair point. I'm technically using MathJax, which requires this to work, but I should have edited it for the post.

Comment: MathJax (used on this site) works with `align` without `$$ $$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use `\mathclap` to insure that the overstack takes up zero horizontal space.

Also, change the `\textbf` instances to `\mathbf` (thanks, Mico).

Finally, ditch the `$$` delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{x} \mid \mathcal{D}, \alpha)
&= \int p(\mathbf{x} \mid \boldsymbol{\theta}) p(\boldsymbol{\theta} \mid \mathcal{D}, \alpha) \text{d} \boldsymbol{\theta}
\\
&\stackrel{\mathclap{\text{Eq 4}}}{=} \int p(\mathbf{x} \mid \boldsymbol{\theta}) p(\boldsymbol{\theta} \mid \alpha') \text{d} \boldsymbol{\theta}
\\
&= p(\mathbf{x} \mid \alpha'). \tag{5}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Thanks, Mico.  Hadn't even noticed.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `\makebox[0pt]{...}` will solve the probl.

Unrelated: do not nest `align` inside `$$ ... $$` – and don't use the plain TeX construct `ˆˆ ... $$` as it will yield incorrect spacing in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
p(\textbf{x} \mid \mathcal{D}, \alpha)
&= \int p(\textbf{x} \mid \boldsymbol{\theta}) p(\boldsymbol{\theta} \mid \mathcal{D}, \alpha) \text{d} \boldsymbol{\theta}
\\
&\stackrel{\text{\makebox[0pt]{Eq 4}}}{=} \int p(\textbf{x} \mid \boldsymbol{\theta}) p(\boldsymbol{\theta} \mid \alpha') \text{d} \boldsymbol{\theta}
\\
&= p(\textbf{x} \mid \alpha'). \tag{5}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]